# Strategy for incorporating geo distance into search results using orderby

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search

I've created an Azure index of "locations", each with a name, address, geography::POINT, etc.

This index is linked to our Azure search, which we use within a Google map. Using the map's current position, I've experimented around with Azure search's geo.distance feature.

Ideally, we could have a happy balance between what location the user searches for, and how close the returned locations are. 
Example: I search for McDonald's, and the results are ordered based on which McD's is closest.

My understanding is that I need to use $orderby=geo.distance[...], but I don't want distance to be the only deciding factor for results. Right now, if I search for "McDonald's" and pass a longitude/latitude of another nearby location (say, KFC), the first result will be KFC and not McDonald's.

Will I need to set up a scoring profile, or are there some ordeby/filter tricks that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to take multiple relevance factors into account (such as textual relevance, distance, freshness, etc.), then setting up a scoring profile is the way to go.

While you can `orderby` multiple fields, it's probably not what you want for this scenario.

See [Azure Search scoring profiles reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/add-scoring-profiles-to-a-search-index) for details on using the scoring profiles.